# Sending an error response after servlet response has been written to

Tags: java, servlets, response

I am writing a data transfer application using a servlet and would like to be able to send an error response if a problem occurs after the servlet response has been written to. Is that possible?

My issue is that I will be sending large compressed csv files that are created from data read from a database. Everything is done with streams so it is possible that an error could occur in the creation of the csv file after the servlet response has been written to. I have seen it happen.

I've noticed that this is only a problem after the servlet OutputStream has been flushed. If it has not been flushed I can send an error response but not after. Since I am dealing with large amounts of data it is not feasible to send everything in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I am writing a data transfer application using a servlet and would like to be able to send an error response if a problem occurs after the servlet response has been written to. Is that possible?*

Not from the server side on. The server cannot take the already flushed bytes back from the client. This is a point of no return. I assume that this concerns a different exception than `IOException` on the response's `Writer` or `OutputStream`.

If it were HTML (even though this is a poor practice; HTML belongs in JSP), you *could* print some JS code which forces a location change like so:

```
try {
    writer.write(someHtml);
} catch (SomeException e) {
    writer.write("<script>window.location = 'error.jsp';</script>");
    // ...
}
```

But this is not possible in non-HTML responses. You'd really need to buffer the entire response in memory or on (temp) disk beforehand. If buffering went flawlessly, then you can pipe it to the response again.

```
try {
    processAndSaveInMemoryOrTempDiskFile(someData, byteArrayOrFileLocation);
} catch (SomeException e) {
    throw new ServletException(e, "Processing some data failed.");
}

copyFromMemoryOrTempDiskToResponse(byteArrayOrFileLocation, writer);
```